# AS not working with COUNT(*) and UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, count, union

So I have joined 3 queries together using UNIONs and want to count the number of lines in the result, but it's a bit weird. It actually works, and gives the correct answer, but it doesn't assign the "AS" part correctly.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
(Long Select Statement)
UNION
(AnotherLong Select Statement)
UNION 
(Even Longer Select Statement)
) 
AS NoOfTweets";
```

The outcome is correct, but instead of assigning it to "NoOfTweets" it assigns it to "Count(*)". If I remove the "AS NoOfTweets" it stops working. If I remove some brackets it stops working. I'm running low on ideas after a long day! I can post the whole code if needs be but would rather not as it's quite long and I think that bit works.

Thanks in advance, Jack.

**Edit: Fixed with:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) NoOfTweets FROM (
(Long Select Statement)
UNION
(AnotherLong Select Statement)
UNION 
(Even Longer Select Statement)
) 
AS NoOfTweets";
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: hmm,whhat if you say SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfTweets ? just guessin here

Comment: So from other posts I read that the AS NoOfTweets goes at the end when you do UNIONs (such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943748/mysql-select-count-union) and it didn't work with the AS NoOfTweets just after the count but it does work if I have both in there - very weird but thanks a lot guys! :)

Answer (score 4):

You aren't putting it in the correct location. The beginning of your query should look like this:

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfTweets`

[More on Column Alias](http://www.geeksengine.com/database/basic-select/column-alias.php)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) NoOfTweets FROM 
(Long Select Statement)
UNION
(AnotherLong Select Statement)
UNION 
(Even Longer Select Statement)
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NoOfTweets FROM 
(Long Select Statement)
UNION
(AnotherLong Select Statement)
UNION 
(Even Longer Select Statement)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `AS` exactly after the item you are counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `NoOfTweets`
FROM ( ... )
```

Also be careful with the `"` you have near the end. Or maybe it comes from a longer string.

Comment: Yes, the " comes from something else.

Answer (score 1):

The error is `Every derived table must have its own alias` which is something I didn't know, so thanks for the education :)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d30f4/4

Nice of MySQL to give an explanation - I tried with MS SQL on SQLFiddle and just got `Incorrect syntax near ')'.` which isn't so helpful!

So, your 'NoOfTweets' is the name given to the results column, and also to the 'derived table' which is required by the SQL engine but could be a different name ... it's not returned in the results. The point of naming a derived table is in case you wish to JOIN to other tables and reference the fields in the joins.